# When I encrypt or decrypt a file with AES, there are weird characters in the End of the file, could that be a buffer issue or a AES issue?

Tags: java, file, encryption

I want to encrypt some data end decrypt it later. When I do there will be weird characters in the end of the file.

I tried to fix the buffersize when its a small file. BUT when the file is bigger, I assume there are weird values that are in the buffer that are just put into the file which are not flushed or somewhere else on the disk.
But I don't know how to deal with that with really big files from which I don't know the exact size.

What can I do to have a more dynamic buffer without exceeding the exact filesize which I am reading/writing?

```java
    private static void writeBytes(FileInputStream fis, ByteArrayOutputStream baos, FileOutputStream fos, long inSize)
            throws IOException {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        int read = 0;
        int bufsize = inSize < 1024 ? Math.toIntExact(inSize) : 1024;
        byte[] buf = new byte[bufsize];

        while ((read = fis.read(buf)) > 0) {
            byte[] ret = buf;
            //I think i should make it here more dynamica because i only need 
            //the new read data
            rounds++;
            ret = startEncryption(ret, baos);
            fos.write(ret);

        }

        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        fis.close();

    }
```

**INPUTFILE.txt**

```
Hello StackOverflow
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
Some more Values exceeding 1024 Bytes
Some more Values exceeding 1024 Bytes
Some more Values exceeding 1024 Bytes
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
Bye StackOverflow
```

then encryption and then decryption

**OUTPUTFILE.txt**

```
Hello StackOverflow
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
Some more Values exceeding 1024 Bytes
Some more Values exceeding 1024 Bytes
Some more Values exceeding 1024 Bytes
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
testvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvaluestestvalues
Bye StackOverflowAZØgZ—»:ÔU
ßøëdKBqDûî=üõU,Ôžð~SÂ¤‘H—[„FUùP!S?ª7­+Xnf ´ŸŸ‰Q¡yB3ÑJ€†€Þt2
:ÂSø¿#¡™,Íô1Lä•²{nÿb>òVc•<ùhÇéJŒìÄí€•¿šãe5³X”ââªüÄUÐNØÛzc!oläÃÝ“ª9iÛÂÐ  êÞ¡Þ)òSþ-Ðét½   |ˆ&š'wÌAr9ö[ì·K$rI2¸ˆÕ5õ[1X¿°¹W¡'Ù>ñg–…$}‘˜mnòÛò¢z­ÔŠÍBØÊH¸[®âù l+½&ˆ¸´üô°Žùdzè³‡oÆ=ó×.ôNÛºi{z·ˆcø¯þÁ›<n?»Ñµ¼¼üÌ Y÷ÎCÚAbýK¡ƒÿÈù‡)´ž|/Åÿˆ(ë¤_ï|ÛL=¹Ã7¾JXº¿ÍoIŸY¬ôÍÙQÀÒ¸~ò!aËæÆ×"(›Ÿ¥¹°‚_ ‹Qj‚†a‰3)‰{Ãç|e
```

there are some weird values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    while ((read = fis.read(buf)) > 0) {
        byte[] ret = Arrays.copyOf(buf, read);
```

Or pass limiting info if there is such an overloaded method:

```
    ... (buf, 0, read);
```

---

***By the way***

Do not use textual input with a Reader (actually you did indeed not use it):

Remove

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
```

Or at least indicate which encoding the read bytes are in:

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: Thank you! That was the Issue. I oversaw that the "read()" return value has more meaning than only "nothing to read" or "somethin to read". 
this is exactly what i needed.  
Thank you. 
And I saw this exact behaviour is documented... 
I should read more carefully.

Comment: Also I have some more read parts of this application. I circumventend this with setting the property of the system charset to UTF 8 : 
```System.setProperty("file.encoding","UTF-8");```


```charset = Charset.class.getDeclaredField("defaultCharset");

   charset.setAccessible(true);

   charset.set(null,null);```

do you think that is also ok or advisable ?

Answer (score 3):

You're always processing the whole buffer, even though the last read most likely will not fill the buffer completely. You need to use the `read` variable to know how many bytes were read, then process the `byte[]` only up to that limit.

Comment: Yes this is what i assumed i didn't know exactly what to do. Also now I know that the read() parameter meant more than only "read" or "nothing to read" . Now its working.
Thank you